# Excel: Find lowest value in range determined by a second column

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to create a formula that will compare the value in one column and give the lowest value in another column.

For example if column A has a product code and column B has a price, how can I get column C to compare the values in column A to give the lowest stock price for each product code?

Comment: what have u tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

There's no `MINIF` (that's min if, not mini f) function (yet?), so back to the old days when one had to use array formulas before `COUNTIF` and `SUMIF` came about:

[image: minif]

`=MIN(IF($A$2:$A$8=A2,$B$2:$B$8))` in C2 and drag down. Be sure to enter as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of just <kbd>Enter</kbd>